# How to pass multiple parameter from view to controller without ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass multiple parameters from view to controller using jquery without an ajax call and I don't want to use ajax, Because that return is in jquery but I want to return view.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".addCF").click(function () {
            var Resource = $("#ResourceId option:selected").text();
            alert(Resource);
            var Description = $("#ResourceDescription ").val();
            alert(Description);
            var Count = $("#ResourceCount option:selected").text();
            alert(Count);
            var Cost = $("#ResourceCostId option:selected").text();
            alert(Cost);
            var Duration = $("#ResourceDuration option:selected").text();
            alert(Duration);

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ResourceList", "Home")',
                data: { Resource: Resource, Description: Description, Count: Count, Cost: Cost, Duration: Duration },
                datetype: 'json',
                contenttype: "application/json",
                type: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                    location.reload();

                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could make ajax request to the controller that return view then try to update the view using jquery `html()` method.

Comment: i can do this but some problem

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: when ajax success the value not get in html format.i will also try

Comment: That normal because you have `datetype: 'json',` in your ajax request.

Comment: Please add your View code, so that we can find out  what actually you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a form to submit. Then use `.submit()`  https://api.jquery.com/submit/ If you are using razor your can create a from like this.

```
@Html.BeginForm("YourAction", "YourController", FormMethod.Post)
```

Then have your controller return a view.

Comment: My forms in two submit button